# How to split a comma-separated value

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have table myTable with field like this

```
tranType              Source
-------------------------------------
RC,RD,RF,RR           PB,CM
```

I want to create stored procedure that use value of tranType and Source as condition in my query

```
select * 
from myTable
where Source = @valSource  -- PB (check for each value from Source)
  AND tranType = @valTrantype  -- RC(check for each value from tranType)
```

it will check all of the value in that field

Comment: Did you try WHERE CHARINDEX(@valSource, Source) > -1 AND CHARINDEX(@valTrantype, tranType) > -1?

Comment: im doing like this <SUBSTRING(Value1,0,charindex(',',Value1))> but it can read the second & after that value @Biscuits

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has a new STRING_SPLIT function, otherwise you can roll your own. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please check with following:

```
select * from myTable 

where find_in_set(@valSource,Source) 

AND find_in_set(@valtranType,tranType)
```

Comment: how to set <@valSource / @valtranType> @KartikShah??

Comment: you set set like: Declare @valSource varchar(8);

Comment: how <@valSource> can get the value from Source field?i mean how read/get each the data of the comma delimiter @KartikShah

Comment: If your variable "valSource" has any value, and if "Source" database field has comma separated values into the table, then value of valSource will surely be compared in "Source" database field.